# System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 8271, position 163

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I am writing a simple XML parser which would pass this XML output: http://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_rss.php?id=187000

The full C# code is:

```
    protected void LoadXML()
    {
        XDocument ourBlog = XDocument.Load("http://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_rss.php?id=187000");
        ourBlog.Declaration.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
        XNamespace NameSpace = "http://www.cpalead.com/feeds/campinfo.php";
        var XMLItem = from item in ourBlog.Descendants("item")
                      select new
                      {
                          title = item.Element("title").Value,
                          link = item.Element("link").Value,
                          guid = item.Element("guid").Value,
                          description = item.Element("description").Value,
                          campinfoamount = item.Element(NameSpace + "amount").Value,
                          campinfocampid = item.Element(NameSpace + "campid").Value,
                          campinfocountry = item.Element(NameSpace + "country").Value,
                          campnfotype = item.Element(NameSpace + "type").Value,
                          campinfoepc = item.Element(NameSpace + "epc").Value,
                          campinforatio = item.Element(NameSpace + "ratio").Value
                      };

        foreach (var item in XMLItem)
        {
            offers.InnerHtml += item.title + item.campinforatio + "<br>";
        }

    }
```

offers is a div element.
When I run this code I get an "System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 8271, position 163." error
As you can see I also set Encoding using ourBlog.Declaration.Encoding = "";
I have tried:

- ISO-8859-1
- UTF-8
- windows-1251
- windows 1252
- UTF-16

I don't know what else to try.
Do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Stack Trace is:

Source Error:

```
Line 19:         protected void LoadXML()
Line 20:         {
Line 21:             XDocument ourBlog = XDocument.Load("http://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_rss.php?id=187000");
Line 22:             ourBlog.Declaration.Encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
Line 23:             XNamespace NameSpace = "http://www.cpalead.com/feeds/campinfo.php";
```

Stack Trace:

```
[XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 8271, position 163.]
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +69
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) +116
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount) +197
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount) +131
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData() +188
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars) +482
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue() +62
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value() +74
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r) +505
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o) +48
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) +283
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options) +58
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri) +6
WebApplication3.Earn._default.LoadXML() in c:\Users\WinDrop\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Earn\default.aspx.cs:21
WebApplication3.Earn._default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\WinDrop\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Earn\default.aspx.cs:16
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Some characters are illegal in XML no matter what the encoding is (e.g. some characters with code under 32) - maybe this is your case?

Comment: If there are illegal characters in XML then why I can open it in IE and Chrome?

Comment: Dude, the fact that you can open some website in IE and Chrome is not something that you should take as a guarantee that it represents valid XML. With the specific example you have shown on this website, you could try any XML validator and it will simply bomb as invalid XML. So it's pretty normal that you would get an exception when you attempt to load invalid XML in a XML parser.

Comment: My friend wrote a parser for the same page in PHP and it works absolutely fine. All he had to do is set content-type in the header to UTF-8. Wouldn't this mean that XML is fine?

Comment: Is there any way to somehow jump over the row that throws and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a working solution here.

Here is the new code:

```
protected void LoadXML()
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        using (var sourceStream = wc.OpenRead("http://www.cpalead.com/dashboard/reports/campaign_rss.php?id=187000"))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
            {
                XDocument ourBlog = XDocument.Load(reader);
                XNamespace NameSpace = "http://www.cpalead.com/feeds/campinfo.php";
                var XMLItem = from item in ourBlog.Descendants("item")
                              select new
                              {
                                  title = item.Element("title").Value,
                                  link = item.Element("link").Value,
                                  guid = item.Element("guid").Value,
                                  description = XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(item.Element("description").Value),
                                  amount = item.Element(NameSpace + "amount").Value,
                                  campid = item.Element(NameSpace + "campid").Value,
                                  country = item.Element(NameSpace + "country").Value,
                                  type = item.Element(NameSpace + "type").Value,
                                  epc = item.Element(NameSpace + "epc").Value,
                                  ratio = item.Element(NameSpace + "ratio").Value
                              };

                foreach (var item in XMLItem)
                {
                    offers.InnerHtml += item.title + " : " + item.description + " : " + item.amount + "<br />"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275825/how-to-prevent-system-xml-xmlexception-invalid-character-in-the-given-encoding

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file is indeed invalid. It's encoding is obviously UTF-8. But there's a problem on line 8271.

The line basically looks like this:

```
    <description>eMusic δίνει οπαδούς μουσικής της φανταστική συναλλάσσεται για μεγάλη μουσική, κατά μέσο όρο περίπου τα μισά από Amazon ή το iTunes κατάστημα. Έναρξ_</description>
```

But right before the closing tag where I put the underscore, the data seems to be cut off in the middle of a UTF-8 multi-byte character. In hex it looks like this:

CF 81 CE BE CE 3C 2F 64 65

CF 81 CE BE are the Greek letters `ρξ`, 3C 2F 64 65 is `</de`. But the remaining CE starts a multi-byte sequence that is cut off. The value is cut off at 255 bytes!

You need to fix the source file. It's invalid. And 255 bytes isn't a random length in IT. Probably more data is missing.

Comment: The problem is that it's not my file. The file is provided by a 3rd party. 
Is there any way to skip that line and just ignore it?

Comment: You would need to write a preprocessor that checks for valid UTF-8 characters and discards all invalid sequences. It's not rocket science if you like bit fiddling.

Comment: Omg, sounds like a complicated task..but oh well, don't have a choice, will have to do a bit of googling and do it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's some C code that checks for valid UTF-8: http://snowplow.org/martin/utf8checker/

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really help at all as I don't know C at all.
And I am only learning C# as well...
Thanks for your help anyway, Don't want to take any more time of yours. Will try to google for some C# solutions :)