# XDocument.Load() with special character in xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I know google is full of this, but I couldn't make it work after hours of trying.

So here's foo.xml:

```
<Root>
    <Child>a</Child>
</Root>
```

XDocument.Load("foo.xml") works great.

Here is bar.xml:

```
<Root>
    <Child>á</Child>
</Root>
```

XDocument.Load("bar.xml") throws a System.Xml.XmlException:

> {"Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 2, position 9."}

How should I progress?

Comment: Have you checked this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275825/how-to-prevent-system-xml-xmlexception-invalid-character-in-the-given-encoding?

Comment: Make sure to save your file as UTF-8.

Comment: Your XML is perfectly valid, so this has nothing to do with XML.  It's likely to do with encoding of the file.

Comment: Encoding to UTF8 solved my  problem. However it did only work with in the example above, with my original xml, it didn't. Since I was constalntly testing on that before this stackoverflow post, I couldn't make it work. Now the trick was to copypaste the content to a new file, encode to UTF8 and it magically started to work. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

No magic here, I just had to encode the xml to UTF8.