# C# Parsing XML in ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a tool for validating XML files grabbed from a mainframe. For reasons beyond my control every XML file is encoded in ISO 8859-1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO 8859-1"?>
```

My C# application utilizes the System.XML library to parse the XML and eventually a string of a message contained within one of the child nodes.

If I manually remove the XML encoding line it works just fine. But i'd like to find a solution that doesn't require manual intervention. Are there any elegant approaches to solving this? Thanks in advance.

The exception that is thrown reads as:

> System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll. System does not support 'ISO 8859-1' encoding. Line 1, position 31

My code is

```
XMLDocument xmlDoc = new XMLDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(//fileLocation);
```

Comment: Show your code pls.

Comment: What's the actual code? What's the actual message of the error? What's the actual document? `XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO 8859-1\"?><a />")` works fine. (That's `System.Xml.Linq` of course, not plain old `System.Xml`.) If all else fails, obviously, you could just do a `String.Replace` to strip out the directive before parsing the result as XML.

Comment: The error it throws is: System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll. System does not support 'ISO 8859-1' encoding. Line 1, position 31. Put simply, the code follows as:  `XMLDocument xmlDoc = new XMLDocument(); xmlDoc.Load(//fileLocation)`. And that's the line that it fails.

Comment: Sorry I edited it into my reply, I didn't know that pressing enter submitted my comment. I'm new to this site - apologies.

Comment: Hold shift if you need a new line :)

Comment: The problem is that `ISO 8859-1` is not a recognized built-in encoding name. `ISO-8859-1` is. Silly but true. Prior to .NET 4.6 (which allows you to register additional encoding providers) I don't know if there's a way to add encoding aliases, but I doubt it. Based on that there's a host of possible workarounds, though (the easiest being adding the hyphen...), like first reading the file manually and then using `.LoadXml` (which ignores the encoding in the directive, as the string is already necessarily UTF-16 internally). If the file is too large for that, you'll have to get more subtle.

Comment: The solution described in [this answer to _How to prevent System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8275868/1336654) works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jeroen pointed out in a comment, the encoding should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO 8859-1"?>
```

(missing dash `-`).

You can use a `StreamReader` with an explicit encoding to read the file anyway:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("//fileLocation", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
  var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.Load(reader);
  // ...
}
```

(from answer by `competent_tech` in other thread I linked in an earlier comment).

If you do not want the `using` statement, I guess you can do:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("//fileLocation", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
```

---

Instead of `XmlDocument`, you can use [the `XDocument` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) in the namespace `System.Xml.Linq` if you refer the assembly `System.Xml.Linq.dll` (since .NET 3.5). It has static methods like `Load(Stream)` and `Parse(string)` which you can use as above.

Comment: I ended up using `xmlDoc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("//fileLocation", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));` and it works great. Thanks!